# Android Splash activity not redirecting after first time setup

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

I have a settings activity i want to show on first time setup only.

Then i have a loading splash screen which redirects after 5 seconds.

However when ive saved my settings activity, it goes to the splash page, but the splash page just gets stuck and doesnt redirect.

On every other startup after the settings have been seen it all works fine. Its just on the first time startup it is buggy.

Any help please?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
        // get shared preferences
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // first time run?
        if (pref.getBoolean("firstTimeRun", true)) {
            // start the preferences activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
            //get the preferences editor
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            // avoid for next run
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeRun", false);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of the Activity's lifecycle. When you came back from the settings activity, onCreate is not called again. To fix you can simply override onResume() and move

```
// get shared preferences
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // first time run?
        if (pref.getBoolean("firstTimeRun", true)) {
            // start the preferences activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
            //get the preferences editor
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            // avoid for next run
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeRun", false);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
```

inside it (removing the whole thing from onCreate)

Comment: So what do i do? Sorry am confused on what you mean

Comment: move the snippet inside onResume. That's all

Comment: where is onresume haha sorry bit of a beginner

Comment: it got lost in the documentation

Comment: I put it in     protected void onResume() { } but the app just crashes on launch now

Comment: Ah forgot to call super.onResume, it seems to be fixed now thanks a lot!